# What is it called: "a scoop"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> scoop [countable] a tool like a large spoon with a deep bowl, used for
>   picking up substances in powder form like flour, or for serving food
>   like ice cream
>
> Use an ice-cream scoop.

---

This is common in Asia, it looks like a very large scoop but is not used to scoop ice-cream.It is used to scoop water probably from a bucket for example, but sometimes people can wash the fruits in it.

[image]

[image]

What is it called: "**a scoo**p"?

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't refer to two words. the listner will understand which scoop you mean from the context, if you guys are talking about ice cream someone might say "get a scoop" and you wouldn't get that big thing in the picture, rather you'd bring the small one meant for, well, scooping ice cream and if you're extracting water from a bucket (for whatever reason :) ) you'll get the scoop in the picture. :)

Comment: Yes, there are different types of scoop. You could also call the one for water a _dipper_. I don't know if you can see the constellation [Ursa Major](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Big_Dipper#English) in your country, but it is sometimes called 'The Big Dipper' because it looks like a saucepan or ladle.

Comment: From the description "used to scoop water probably from a bucket" I would call it a [**ladle**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ladle) but from your pictures I would call it a "small pan" with a variety of uses.

Comment: @WeatherVane, but it is plastic & can't be used for cooking

Comment: I have a small plastic pan like that, which I use for cooking although obviously it can't be put on a flame. I use it to heat up soups, beans, tomatoes etc, in a microwave oven.